# Confluent HDFS Connector is losing messages

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Community, could you please help me to understand why **~3%** of my messages don't end up in `HDFS`? I wrote a simple producer in `JAVA` to generate 10 million messages.

```java
public static final String TEST_SCHEMA = "{"
        + "\"type\":\"record\","
        + "\"name\":\"myrecord\","
        + "\"fields\":["
        + "  { \"name\":\"str1\", \"type\":\"string\" },"
        + "  { \"name\":\"str2\", \"type\":\"string\" },"
        + "  { \"name\":\"int1\", \"type\":\"int\" }"
        + "]}";

public KafkaProducerWrapper(String topic) throws UnknownHostException {
    // store topic name
    this.topic = topic;

    // initialize kafka producer
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("client.id", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    config.put("bootstrap.servers", "myserver-1:9092");
    config.put("key.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
    config.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
    config.put("schema.registry.url", "http://myserver-1:8089");
    config.put("acks", "all");

    producer = new KafkaProducer(config);

    // parse schema
    Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
    schema = parser.parse(TEST_SCHEMA);
}

public void send() {
    // generate key
    int key = (int) (Math.random() * 20);

    // generate record
    GenericData.Record r = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    r.put("str1", "text" + key);
    r.put("str2", "text2" + key);
    r.put("int1", key);

    final ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, "K" + key, (GenericRecord) r);
    producer.send(record, new Callback() {
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
            if (e != null) {
                logger.error("Send failed for record {}", record, e);
                messageErrorCounter++;
                return;
            }
            logger.debug("Send succeeded for record {}", record);
            messageCounter++;
        }
    });
}

public String getStats() { return "Messages sent: " + messageCounter + "/" + messageErrorCounter; }

public long getMessageCounter() {
    return messageCounter + messageErrorCounter;
}

public void close() {
    producer.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, UnknownHostException {
    // initialize kafka producer
    KafkaProducerWrapper kafkaProducerWrapper = new KafkaProducerWrapper("my-test-topic");

    long max = 10000000L;
    for (long i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        kafkaProducerWrapper.send();
    }

    logger.info("producer-demo sent all messages");
    while (kafkaProducerWrapper.getMessageCounter() < max)
    {
        logger.info(kafkaProducerWrapper.getStats());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    logger.info(kafkaProducerWrapper.getStats());
    kafkaProducerWrapper.close();
}
```

And I use the `Confluent HDFS Connector` in **standalone mode** to write data to `HDFS`. The configuration is as follows:

```sh
name=hdfs-consumer-test
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

topics=my-test-topic

hdfs.url=hdfs://my-cluster/kafka-test
hadoop.conf.dir=/etc/hadoop/conf/
flush.size=100000
rotate.interval.ms=20000

# increase timeouts to avoid CommitFailedException
consumer.session.timeout.ms=300000
consumer.request.timeout.ms=310000

heartbeat.interval.ms= 60000
session.timeout.ms= 100000
```

The connector writes the data into HDFS, but after waiting for 20000 ms (due to `rotate.interval.ms`) not all messages are received.

```scala
scala> spark.read.avro("/kafka-test/topics/my-test-topic/partition=*/my-test-topic*")
  .count()
res0: Long = 9749015
```

Any idea what is the reason for this behavior? Where is my mistake? I'm using **Confluent 3.0.1/Kafka 10.0.0.1**.

Comment: Are you seeing the last few messages are not moved to HDFS? If so, it's likely you are running into the issue described here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/100

Try sending one more message to the topic after the rotate.interval.ms has expired to validate this is what you are running into. If you need to rotate based on time, it's probably a good idea to upgrade to pickup the fix.

Comment: That's the solution! I updated to **Confluent 3.1.1** and I can see all messages in `HDFS`. Do you want to write it as an answer and I give you the kudos you deserve?

Comment: Yep sure, didn't know there was really a difference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing the last few messages are not moved to HDFS? If so, it's likely you are running into the issue described here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/100

Try sending one more message to the topic after the rotate.interval.ms has expired to validate this is what you are running into. If you need to rotate based on time, it's probably a good idea to upgrade to pickup the fix.